# improving the written sql query

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I want to write a SQL query for the problem as defined below, my answer is as below, but I am not sure about the answer, can anyone help me? Is the answer correct, or if not, how can I improve it?

Let us consider the following relational schema about physicians and departments:

- `PHYSICIAN` (PhysicianId, Name, Surname, Specialization, Gender, BirthDate, Department);

  Let every physician be univocally identified by a code and characterized by a name, a surname, a specialization (we assume to record exactly one specialization for each physician), a gender, a birth date, and the relative department (each physician is assigned to one and only one department).
- `DEPARTMENT` (Name, Building, Floor, Chief)

  Let every department be univocally identified by a name and characterized by its location (building and floor) and a chief.

Let us assume that a physician can be the chief of at most one department (the department he/she belongs to). We do not exclude the possibility for two distinct departments to be located at the same floor of the same building.

Define preliminarily primary keys, other candidate keys (if any), and foreign keys (if any). Then, formulate an SQL query to compute the following data (exploiting aggregate functions only if they are strictly necessary):

- the departments with both male and female physicians, whose physicians are all born after 1955, that is, they are all at most 64 years old.

My answer is as below:

```sql
create view table X as {
select d.Name
from department d inner join PHYSICIAN p on 
d.department=f.name
where gender="Female" and gender="Male and birthdate>1955

select *
from X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will not return any records because 'gender' field cannot be equal to Female and Male at the same time.
My suggestion is something like:

```
select distinct d.*
  from departments d
  inner join physicians m on d.name = m.department and m.gender = 'Male'
  inner join physicians f on d.name = f.department and f.gender = 'Female'
  left join physicians o on d.name = o.department and p.birthdate < '1955-01-01'
  where o.id is null
```

The idea is to find at least one male and one female for each department. After that find one old person for each department and filter out all departments that have such an old person.

Comment: I've updated the query to use department name. Also notice that this query doesn't use any aggregation functions whereas @Parfait's answer contains count function that contradicts your problem requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since question asks only about departments consider using a subquery and not join to physician table. Additionally, no person can be male and female at same time (non-binary categories would be their own type), so current logic fails.

Consider checking age and gender separately in correlated queries. An aggregate query can check if *all* department members are born after 1955.

```sql
select d.Name
from department d 
where d.name in
  (select p.department from PHYSICIAN p where p.gender='Female')
and d.name in
  (select p.department from PHYSICIAN p where p.gender='Male') 
and d.name in
  (select p.department
   from PHYSICIAN p
   group by p.department
   having count(*) = sum(p.birthdate >= '1956-01-01'))
```

Comment: I don't understand the part, why we need to check the name twice from physician with gender male and female ? Isn't it enough to check similar to the count check in having clause ?

Comment: thank you, can I ask what this part is doing?    having count(*) = sum(p.birthdate >= '1956-01-01'))

Comment: First two subqueries checks department if at least one physician is in either gender. Last subquery checks if all physicians born after 1955. `count(*)` returns count of all rows and `sum(...)` sums the `True` (=1) for that logic. If all physicians in that department are born after 1955 it would equal all physicians in that department.