# Writing sql without aggregation function

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL query for the problem as defined below, I am not sure about the answer, can anyone help me? Is the answer correct, or if not, how can I improve it?

I have used aggregation function, how can I improve it, to write an sql without aggregation function?

Let us consider the following relational schema about physicians and departments:

- `PHYSICIAN` (PhysicianId, Name, Surname, Specialization, Gender, BirthDate, Department);

  Let every physician be univocally identified by a code and characterized by a name, a surname, a specialization (we assume to record exactly one specialization for each physician), a gender, a birth date, and the relative department (each physician is assigned to one and only one department).
- `DEPARTMENT` (Name, Building, Floor, Chief)

  Let every department be univocally identified by a name and characterized by its location (building and floor) and a chief.

Let us assume that a physician can be the chief of at most one department (the department he/she belongs to). We do not exclude the possibility for two distinct departments to be located at the same floor of the same building.

I want to formulate an SQL query to compute the following data (exploiting aggregate functions only if they are strictly necessary):

- the departments which have no male physicians and with at least two physicians whose home city is Venice.

My answer is as below:

```sql
select d.name
from department d
where d.name in (select p.department from physician p where p.gender =! 'Male')
  and d.name in (select p.department from physician p 
                 where HomeCity = 'Venice'
                 group by p.PhysicianId
                 having count > 2)
```

Or:

```
select d.*
from department d
inner join physician p on d.name=p.department and 
p.gender=!"Male"

left join physician o where d.name=o.department and  o.birthdate='venice'

groupby birthdate 
having sum(o. physicianID) >2
```

Comment: Duplicates this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863877/improving-the-written-sql-query/63864144#63864144

Comment: the the sql problem is completely different  that is :the departments which have no male physicians and with at least two physicians whose home city is Venice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both the conditions should apply at the same time, I'd say your answer is correct. I would modify it just a bit:

```
select d.name
from department d
where not exists (select 1 from physician p where p.gender = 'Male' and p.Department = d.name)
  and d.name in (select p.department from physician p 
                 where HomeCity = 'Venice'
                 group by p.department, p.HomeCity
                 having count >= 2)
```

If you go with the inner join solution, you will have to apply a distinct to your select, which will make your query slower.

The `not exists` clause I propose, will create an execution plan, similar to inner join. That is you will not need to compare each name with all the names of the departments without Male employees.

You can't avoid the aggregate function if you want to count something. There is a workaround with `Over` in `TSQL` but I would not recommend it.

Comment: also I modify this part like this:  group by p.PhysicianId , do you think that this modification is correct ?because it asked , **at least two physicians** whose home city is Venice.

Comment: Checks if there is even one row that fits the check. That is if there is even one male employee in for that department. The first one it finds, the query returns

Comment: No, check the updated answer. You group by department and home city. This will count the number of physicians per department/city combination.

Comment: thanks a lot, and  having count > 2, we shouldn't define that having count on what?like                  having count(homecity='venice') > 2)

Comment: @user14269252 . . . Your question says to write the query without an aggregation function but this query uses `group by`.  I can accept that this is correct and that your limitation is merely academic, but this doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: The idea of the question is to optimize and that was why the op wanted to eliminate the group by clause. I'm just stating that to the best of my knowledge, the aggregate is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Despite conditions are different the main idea is the same as in [improving the written sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863877/improving-the-written-sql-query/63864144#63864144).

You need to use the same approach but substitute your own join and where conditions.

**Update**
Here is a version for your case:

```
select distinct d.*
  from departments d
  left join physicians m on d.name = m.department and m.gender = 'Male'
  inner join physicians v1 on d.name = v1.department and v1.homecity = 'Venice'
  inner join physicians v2 on d.name = v2.department and v2.homecity = 'Venice' and v2.id <> v1.id
  where m.id is null
```

Comment: I wrote two different query as I am new to sql, I don't know whether my query is correct or not, I don't think that I asked not a proper question !